# Configure postfix with a threshold for reject_rbl_client

Tags: postfix, spam

I have my postfix main.cf configured with a number of blacklists:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    reject_rbl_client opm.blitzed.org,
    reject_rbl_client zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
    reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
    reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com,
    reject_rbl_client dsn.rfc-ignorant.org,
    reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
    reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
    reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
    reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net
```

An incoming mail was just rejected because it appeared on one of these lists (sorbs.net) but not on the others. Is it possible to configure postfix to only reject if 2 or more lists contain that IP address? I'm hoping this will remove false matches...

Comment: I've been reading about the different lists and it seems that sorbs.net has a tendency to add IPs a little too easily. I'm thinking of just removing those from my config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your postfix version to at least 2.8, and configure [**postscreen**](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html).

It supports complex weighting and thresholds for individual DNSBLs

Comment: Gosh - I'm on Centos5 still and have only 2.3.3...

Comment: Postfix 2.**5** is no longer supported; 2.3 has been EOL for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK what you ask is not possible with a standard postfix configuration.  However, you could delegate the RBL checks to a [postfix policy daemon](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) that would do some custom checking of your own.

I'd suggest you have a look at [the list of such daemons provided on the Postfix website](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#policy).  One of them might suit your needs.  I've not used any of those but, looking at the documentation, the following seems particularly useful:

- [Gross](http://code.google.com/p/gross/): does RBL checks and greylisting and combine them in different ways,
- [policyd-weight](http://www.policyd-weight.org): scores an incoming message depending on header contents, RBL checks and some other DNS queries, then accept or discards the message if the score is too high,
- [postfwd](http://postfwd.org): does a lot more other things too (might be overkill for your needs),